# My server is not listening for file changes

Tags: linux, reactjs, webstorm, file-watcher

I use WebStorm and working with React. from some moment IDE just stoped watching for file changes and now I have to reload my server to see the changes. I have no idea what I did. 
I found this (https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/04/native-file-system-watcher-for-linux/) page, but it's not helpful for me. my /etc/sysctl.conf is now looking like this:

```
# Uncomment the next line to enable TCP/IP SYN cookies
# See http://lwn.net/Articles/277146/
# Note: This may impact IPv6 TCP sessions too
#net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies=1

# Uncomment the next line to enable packet forwarding for IPv4
#net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

# Uncomment the next line to enable packet forwarding for IPv6
#  Enabling this option disables Stateless Address Autoconfiguration
#  based on Router Advertisements for this host
#net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1


###################################################################
# Additional settings - these settings can improve the network
# security of the host and prevent against some network attacks
# including spoofing attacks and man in the middle attacks through
# redirection. Some network environments, however, require that these
# settings are disabled so review and enable them as needed.
#
# Do not accept ICMP redirects (prevent MITM attacks)
#net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
#net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
# _or_
# Accept ICMP redirects only for gateways listed in our default
# gateway list (enabled by default)
# net.ipv4.conf.all.secure_redirects = 1
#
# Do not send ICMP redirects (we are not a router)
#net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 0
#
# Do not accept IP source route packets (we are not a router)
#net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_source_route = 0
#net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_source_route = 0
#
# Log Martian Packets
#net.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians = 1
#

###################################################################
# Magic system request Key
# 0=disable, 1=enable all
# Debian kernels have this set to 0 (disable the key)
# See https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysrq.txt
# for what other values do
#kernel.sysrq=1

###################################################################
# Protected links
#
# Protects against creating or following links under certain conditions
# Debian kernels have both set to 1 (restricted) 
# See https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/fs.txt
#fs.protected_hardlinks=0
#fs.protected_symlinks=0
#fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288
```

Comment: by the way, nodemon works fine, if it is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens when the project is large and contains many files.

I have also faced a similar issue. I solved it by increasing the file watch size.

Just uncomment the line `fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288` from the file `/etc/sysctl.conf` and save it. To load the new setting run `sudo sysctl -p` in the terminal

Comment: so... silly question, but # means comment? so file in fact is empty?

Comment: Yes, # are comments on Linux file system